# Execute multiple SQL queries in one statement using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and I want to execute multiple SQL queries in one statement using python, but I am not able to find the appropriate way to do so.

I wrote following code but its throwing an error as `" DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended."`

```
import cx_Oracle;

SQLQuery = "select x from xyz where p= 'sn'; select * from abs where a ='qw';"
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('username', 'password', 'server')

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute(SQLQuery) #its throwing error here
```

It would be great if one can suggest me the appropriate function for executing the multiple queries in one call.
Appreciate your response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont cleary understand , why You need to execute many statements in one query ? . The reason why it's build for being able to handle one query per call is that every query returns something and in your case we cannot decide which query result should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to achieve with this?

Technically you could try to get rows from two tables or try to combine rows from different tables, but all this is directly done in SQL.

Comment: Yea exacly, there are SQL statements like `union` etc.

Comment: I am trying to perform SQL injection attack where the input ll be taken from the user and user may perform a SQL injection attack. For this purpose I want to know how can I execute multiple SQL queries in one statement using Python

Comment: I guess you want to test multiple queries simultaneously against the same server? If so I'd suggest using multiple threads or even process.

Comment: Yup DerMolly. I ll try with that. Thanks much

Answer (score -1):

Remove ; (semicolon)  at the end of query and it should run fine.